# How to solve problem when deploying the application? when using 'flutter build appbundle' it displays this error in the terminal:

Tags: flutter

- What went wrong:
  A problem occurred configuring root project 'android'.

> Could not resolve all files for configuration ':classpath'.
> Could not find com.android.tools.build:gradle:7.5..
> Searched in the following locations:
> - https://dl.google.com/dl/android/maven2/com/android/tools/build/gradle/7.5./gradle-7.5..pom
> - https://repo.maven.apache.org/maven2/com/android/tools/build/gradle/7.5./gradle-7.5..pom
> Required by:
> project :

- Try:

> Run with --stacktrace option to get the stack trace.
> Run with --info or --debug option to get more log output.
> Run with --scan to get full insights.

- Get more help at https://help.gradle.org

This is the error message that appears in the terminal, the gradle version is the same, 7.5 and I can't solve the problem

I tried to update gradle, I tried to modify the classpath in the build.gradle dependencies and still nothing works and there doesn't seem to be information of similar problems on the internet

Answer (score 0):

**Run these command**

- flutter pub cache clean
- flutter clean
- flutter pub cache repair
- flutter pub get

**If issues not solved , update your classpath version to latest**.